# Show that $\left(\bigcup_{i \in I}A_{i}\right )^{c}=\bigcap_{i \in I}A_{i}^{c}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm learning for a test and I think there will be some task similar to this one. I'd like to know if I did it correct and if not can you please say how to do it correctly?

> Let $\Omega$ be a set, let $I$ be an index-set and let $A \subseteq
> \Omega$ and $A_{i} \subseteq \Omega$ for all $i \in I$.
>
> Show that $$\left(\bigcup_{i \in I}A_{i}\right )^{c}=\bigcap_{i \in
> I}{A_{i}}^{c}$$

We defined this in our readings:

Complement: $A^{c} \equiv \bar{A}= \left\{x \in \Omega; (x \notin A)\right\}$

and $$\overline{\bigcup_{i \in I}A_{i}}=\bigcap_{i \in
I}\overline{A_{i}}$$

I did it like this:

$$\left(\bigcup_{i \in I}A_{i}\right)^{c}=\overline{\bigcup_{i \in I}A_{i}}=\bigcap_{i \in
I}\overline{A_{i}}=\bigcup_{i \in I}{A_{i}}^{c}$$

Comment: The first image you inserted, $\overline{\bigcup_{i∈I} A_i} = \bigcap_{i ∈ I} \overline{A_i}$ – is that really supposed to be a definition? Or is that a proposition already proved in your readings? It would be really weird if that was a definition. If it’s not, my guess is that you are supposed to produce or reproduce the proof of that proposition, so you cannot use it itself in doing so. The task certainly is not supposed to be to merely recognise $A^c$ and $\overline A$ as being diferent notations for the same thing.

Comment: It wasn't proved but our professor wrote it exactly like that on the table and he said what we had in readings is allowed to be used. So I just used it :P How would you do it if it wasn't allowed? Is it possible?

Comment: Sure it is. I propose you give it a try to explicitly prove the proposition. And a little advice: Commit to one of the notations, either $A^c$ or $\overline A$, for set-theoretic complements. Otherwise, you might confuse yourself and your writing becomes less clear. If you can’t manage to prove it yourself, look up “de Morgan’s laws”.

Comment: Please note that [in the linked duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/442290/prove-that-c-left-bigcup-alpha-in-i-a-alpha-right-bigcap-alpha-in-ic?noredirect=1&lq=1), $C(*)$ is taken to mean $(*)^c$.  I reopened the question after adding the tag "proof verification", since your question is not asking "how" to prove it, but rather verification of your work.

Comment: See also [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207570/infinite-demorgan-laws) and other questions [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/207570)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a basic beginner's guide on how to solve this question.

So you want to show $(\cup_{i\in I} A_{i})^{c} = \cap_{i \in I} A_{i}^{c}$.

Notice that the thing on either side of the $=$ is a set.  So you are trying to show two sets are equal.  If you want to show $B = C$ for sets $B$ and $C$, the standard way to approach this is to show $B \subseteq C$ and $C \subseteq B$.  If you show they are subsets of each other, then that's good enough to show they are equal.

Okay, so we need to show then **two statements**:

1. $(\cup_{i\in I} A_{i})^{c} \subseteq \cap_{i \in I} A_{i}^{c}$
2. $\cap_{i \in I} A_{i}^{c} \subseteq (\cup_{i\in I} A_{i})^{c}$.

I'll show you how to do 1, and you will have to do 2 yourself, but the way to do 2 is very similar to the way to do 1 so if you understand what I'm about to say, then you'll be able to do 2.  Feel free to ask me questions in the comments about your attempt.

Okay, so I want to prove $(\cup_{i\in I} A_{i})^{c} \subseteq \cap_{i \in I} A_{i}^{c}$.  To show this, I will need to let $x$ be any element of the left hand side $(\cup_{i\in I} A_{i})^{c}$, and I will need to show it is in the right hand side $\cap_{i \in I} A_{i}^{c}$.

Alright, then let $x \in (\cup_{i\in I} A_{i})^{c}$ be any arbitrary element.  To show it is in $\cap_{i \in I} A_{i}^{c}$, let's start by inspecting what it means for $x$ to be in $(\cup_{i\in I} A_{i})^{c}$.

Since $x \in (\cup_{i\in I} A_{i})^{c}$, that means $x$ is **not** in $\cup_{i\in I} A_{i}$.  Okay, but if $x$ is not in that union, then that means it is not in any $A_{i}$ for any $i$ (since if it was on one of them, it would be in the union).  But if $x$ is not in $A_{i}$ for any $i$, then that means $x$ is in $A_{i}^{c}$ for every $i$.  But if $x \in A_{i}^{c}$ for every $i$, then that means $x \in \cap_{i \in I} A_{i}^{c}$.  But this is what we wanted to show!  So we are done with this part.

Now you have to prove statement 2.  If you have any questions, feel free to ask me in the comments.

Comment: Let $x \in \bigcap_{i \in I} A_{i}^{c} \Rightarrow x$ isn't in $A_{i}$ but could be because of $\bigcap_{i \in I}$. For the right side, $x$ cannot be in $\bigcup_{i \in I}A_{i}$ and if we now take its intersection, it won't be in any $A_{i}$ again because left side it's not in $A_{i}$ and right side it's not in $A_{i}$ either. ?

Comment: @cnmesr So if I understand your first sentence, then the idea in the first sentence is right.  If $x \in \cap_{i \in I} A_{i}^{c}$, then $x$ is in $A_{i}^{c}$ **for every** $i$, since that's what intersection means, right?  That means $x$ is **not in** $A_{i}$ for any $i$, since it is in the complement for every $i$.  But if $x$ is not in $A_{i}$ for any $i$, what does that tell you about $x$ and the set $\cup_{i \in I} A_{i}$?  Is $x$ in this set or not?

Comment: $x$ is not in the set $\bigcup_{i \in I}A_{i}$

Comment: ..and because on both sides x is not in $A_{i}$ for every $i$ we get true statement?

Comment: @cnmesr Your first comment is right, $x$ is not in $\cup_{i \in I} A_{i}$, so that means $x \in (\cup_{i \in I} A_{i})^{c}$.

Comment: @cnmesr I'm confused with what you mean by "both sides".  For each statement $1$ and $2$, you are supposed to show one thing.  So for 2, which we are discussing in the comments, you want to show $\cap_{i\in I}A_{i}^{c} \subseteq (\cup_{i \in I} A_{i})^{c}$.  To show this, you **assume** $x \in \cap_{i\in I}A_{i}^{c}$, and try to get a logical string of statements that lets you **deduce** as the final statement that $x \in (\cup_{i \in I} A_{i})^{c}$...

Comment: @cnmesr ...  So we start by **assuming** $x \in \cap_{i\in I}A_{i}^{c}$ and then interpret what that means in order to get a logical string of implications which we hope will lead us to the statement $x \in (\cup_{i \in I} A_{i})^{c}$.

Comment: Ok then we know $x$ isn't in $A_{i}$ for all $i$, so yes it must be in all $A_{i}^{c}$ for all $i$ and this means it must be in the intersection of $A_{i}^{c} too?$

Comment: @cnmesr Here is the proof we just constructed for 2 together, but put all together in one form:

We want to show $\cap_{i \in I} A_{i}^{c} \subseteq (\cup_{i \in I} A_{i})^{c}$.  Okay, so let $x \in \cap_{i \in I} A_{i}^{c}$.  Then by the definition of intersection, $x$ is in $A_{i}^{c}$ for every $i$.  That means $x$ is **not in** $A_{i}$ for any $i$, since it is in the complement for every $i$.  But if $x$ is not in $A_{i}$ for any $i$, then $x$ is not in $\cup_{i \in I} A_{i}$ by the definition of union.  But that means $x \in (\cup_{i \in I}A_{i})^{c}$ by definition of complement.  Done.

Comment: @cnmesr Do you see how in my last comment the proof starts with one thing, and logically moves step by step to what we needed to show, which was that $x \in (\cup_{i \in I} A_{i})^{c}$.  Keep your eye on what we want to show, i.e., what our end game is in the proof, when you are doing a proof like this.  For this part, our end game was to get $x \in (\cup_{i \in I} A_{i})^{c}$, so you have to keep that in mind when doing the proofs in order to figure out how to get to that last step.

Comment: I think I understood all now, thanks a lot! :D  Just one last question; it is really as I described in my question, the professor gave us these "definitions" I mentioned above. So, my short and cheap proof which shouldn't be called a proof is correct too?

Comment: @cnmesr Sometimes you can get to short "cheap" proofs based on facts proved in class.  But the proof you gave in the question isn't really a proof, because all it is saying is that you have two notations for complement: $A^{c}$ and $\bar{A}$.  And since the statement holds for notation $\bar{A}$, it holds for $A^{c}$ notation too.  But that's obvious exactly because $A^{c}$ and $\bar{A}$ are notations for the same thing.  I hope I'm making sense.

Comment: So you are saying if this was really mentioned in class as I described in my question, I am allowed to make use of it and my cheap solution would be correct?

Comment: @cnmesr Sure, but I'm also expressing doubt that it was mentioned in class in the way you are thinking about it because it's highly unlikely the instructor intended for you to complete the problem by saying "this was proved in class."  Maybe they put the statement up on the board and told you that they would eventually assign it as homework?  Did the instructor actually prove it, or just mention it?  That's also very important.  If they just mentioned the fact, but didn't prove it in class, then I would say you can't use it as a proof on the homework.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, let's make things a little more clear: you have a set $\Omega$ and a family of subsets of $\Omega$ indexed by $I$: $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$.
You want to prove that $\left(\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i\right)^c=\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i^c$.
You don't actually need any other $A\subseteq \Omega$, I think...

Let's introduce some notation: $U:=\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$, $V:=\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i^c$. Thus, the claim is that $U^c=W$.

We say that $x\in U^c$ iff $x\notin U$, i.e., if $x\notin A_i$, for every $i\in I$ (from the fact that $y\in U$ if there is some $i_0\in I$ - not nec. unique - such that $y\in A_{i_0}$; recall then how quantifiers behave under negation). This means exactly that $x\in A_i^c$ for every $i\in I$, thus, by definition of the intersection, you get $x\in V$. Hence: $U\subseteq V$. Every implication is actually an equivalence (an iff), thus $V\subseteq U$, too.

Answer (score 1):

By definition we have $$\bigcup_{i \in I}A_{i}=\{x\in\Omega:\exists i\in I(x\in A_i)\}$$
and $$\bigcap_{i \in I}{A_{i}^c}=\{x\in\Omega:\forall i\in I(x\notin A_i)\}$$

By the definition of equality of sets we have $$\left(\bigcup_{i \in I}A_{i}\right )^{c}=\bigcap_{i \in I}{A_{i}}^{c}$$ if and only if $$\left(\bigcup_{i \in I}A_{i}\right )^{c}\subseteq\bigcap_{i \in
I}{A_{i}}^{c} \text{ and }\bigcap_{i \in
I}{A_{i}}^{c}\subseteq\left(\bigcup_{i \in I}A_{i}\right )^{c}$$

- Let $x\in\left(\bigcup_{i \in I}A_{i}\right )^{c}$. By the defintion of compliment of a set we have $x\notin \bigcup_{i \in I}A_{i}$. Since $x\notin \bigcup_{i \in I}A_{i}$, by the definition of $\bigcup_{i \in I}A_{i}$ and the axiom of specification we have $x\in\Omega$ and $x\notin A_i$ for all $i\in I$. Since $x\in\Omega$ and $x\notin A_i$ for any $i\in I$, we have $x\in\Omega$ and $x\in A_i^c$ for all $i\in I$. Therefore by the definition of $\bigcap_{i \in
  I}{A_{i}}^{c}$ we have $x\in\bigcap_{i \in
  I}{A_{i}}^{c}$. We thus have $x\in\bigcap_{i \in
  I}{A_{i}}^{c}$ whenever $x\in\left(\bigcup_{i \in I}A_{i}\right )^{c}$. Hence $\left(\bigcup_{i \in I}A_{i}\right )^{c}\subseteq\bigcap_{i \in
  I}{A_{i}}^{c}$.
- Now suppose conversely that we have $x\in\bigcap_{i \in
  I}{A_{i}}^{c}$. By the definition of $\bigcap_{i \in
  I}{A_{i}}^{c}$ we have $x\in\Omega$ and $x\in A_i^c$ for all $i\in I$. In other words, we have $x\in \Omega$ and $x\notin A_i$ for any $i\in I$. Again using the axiom of specification and the definition of $\bigcup_{i \in I}A_{i}$ we have $x\notin\bigcup_{i \in I}A_{i}$. Since $x\notin\bigcup_{i \in I}A_{i}$, we have $x\in\left(\bigcup_{i \in I}A_{i}\right )^{c}$. Since $x\in\left(\bigcup_{i \in I}A_{i}\right )^{c}$ whenever $x\in\bigcap_{i \in I}{A_{i}}^{c}$, we have $\bigcap_{i \in
  I}{A_{i}}^{c}\subseteq\left(\bigcup_{i \in I}A_{i}\right )^{c}$.

Since $\left(\displaystyle\bigcup_{i \in I}A_{i}\right )^{c}\subseteq\displaystyle\bigcap_{i \in
I}{A_{i}}^{c}$ and $\displaystyle\bigcap_{i \in
I}{A_{i}}^{c}\subseteq\left(\displaystyle\bigcup_{i \in I}A_{i}\right )^{c}$, we have $\left(\displaystyle\bigcup_{i \in I}A_{i}\right )^{c}=\displaystyle\bigcap_{i \in I}{A_{i}}^{c}$.

Answer (score 1):

What you did is correct. But since you asked in a comment how to prove the result without using the proposition provided by your professor (which does all the work for you!), you can do it as follows. You should prove that the elements of $\left(\bigcup_{i \in I}A_{i}\right )^{c}$ are precisely the elements of $\bigcap_{i \in I}{A_{i}}^{c}$, because in that case the sets are equal. So you can start by saying *suppose that* $x\in \left(\bigcup_{i \in I}A_{i}\right )^{c}$, and then you will have to show that $x$ is also an element of $\bigcap_{i \in
I}{A_{i}}^{c}$. And after that you have the do the same in the opposite direction. I'll show how to do one direction. Then you can try the other one yourself.

So we start by saying suppose that $x\in \left(\bigcup_{i \in I}A_{i}\right )^{c}$. This means by definition that $x\neq \bigcup_{i \in I}A_{i}$. We have, also by definition, that
$$\bigcup_{i \in I}A_{i} = \{x\in \Omega:x\in A_i\text{ for some }i\in I\}$$ and since $x$ is not an element of this set, there can be no $A_i$ that contains $x$ (for otherwise $x$ *would* be an element of the set). Therefore, for all $i$ we have that $x\notin A_i$, which, by definition, means that $x\in A_i{}^c$ for all $i$. Now, since, again by definition,
$$\bigcap_{i \in I}{A_{i}}^{c} = \{x\in\Omega : x\notin A_i \text{ for all } i\in I\}$$
it follows that $x\in \bigcap_{i \in I}{A_{i}}^{c}$.

So we have now proved that all elements of $\left(\bigcup_{i \in I}A_{i}\right )^{c}$ are also elements of $\bigcap_{i \in I}{A_{i}}^{c}$. If you can now show that the opposite statement also holds, then you have proven that the sets are equal. This second part of the proof is very similar to the part that I have shown you, so it would be a good exercise to try it yourself.