# Prove that $\left(\bigcap_{i \in I}A_{i}\right)^{c}=\bigcup_{i \in I}A_{i}^{c}$ by deduction

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> You know that $\left(\bigcup_{i \in I}A_{i}\right)^{c}= \bigcap_{i \in
> I}A_{i}^{c}$. By this knowledge, deduce that $\left(\bigcap_{i \in
> I}A_{i}\right)^{c}=\bigcup_{i \in I}A_{i}^{c} $

So in a previous task, I had to prove the first thing. It was done by showing that the left side is a real subset of the right side, and the other way around (here is the proof; see the accepted answer:[Show that $\left(\bigcup_{i \in I}A_{i}\right )^{c}=\bigcap_{i \in I}A_{i}^{c}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1978498/show-that-left-bigcup-i-in-ia-i-right-c-bigcap-i-in-ia-ic)).

I could prove this the same way but they want me to deduce it from the previous proof but I don't know how to do that : /

But if I look at $$\left(\bigcup_{i \in I}A_{i}\right)^{c}$$

and

$$\left(\bigcap_{i \in
I}A_{i}\right)^{c}$$

they are very similar, just that the first one is union and the other one is  intersection. So taking the complement gives the opposite of each other and that's why we get to

$$\left(\bigcap_{i \in
I}A_{i}\right)^{c}=\bigcup_{i \in I}A_{i}^{c}$$

?

Comment: Please use only _relevant_ tags for your questions. Wrongly tagged questions clutter the search results for people interested in [tag:some-other-topic], and people interested in the topic of your question may not see it because they ignore one or more of the tags irrelevant for the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you know that 
$$
\bigcap A_i^c = \left(\bigcup A_i \right)^c
$$
Now take the complement on both sides. (This preserves the equality).
$$
\left (\bigcap A_i^c \right)^c = \left(\left(\bigcup A_i \right)^c\right)^c = \bigcup A_i 
$$
Now simply "rename" all $A_i^c$ into $B_i$ and so $A_i = B_i^c$, you then get :
$$
\left (\bigcap B_i \right)^c = \bigcup B_i^c
$$
Which is what you wanted to prove.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Didn't expect at all it would be done like that :P

Comment: is it really allowed to just rename the variables?

Comment: Yeah as long as it is consistent. The main point is that if I set $B := A^c$ then I must set $B^c := A$. I'm just calling the complement of $A$ (which is a perfectly defined set) in another way.