# Prove that $B \setminus (\bigcup_{i\in I} A_i) = \bigcap_{i\in I} (B \setminus A_i)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, quantifiers

Help prove it by first proving that $\Rightarrow$ and later $\Leftarrow$ . I'm confused, if I let $x$ be arbitrary and later want to prove that $x \in B$ , and I've got $∀i ∈ I\,(x ∈ B\; \text{ and }\;x ∉ A_i)$. If I suppose $i ∈ I$, and obtain $x ∈ B$, still I've only proven $∀i ∈ I\,(x ∈ B)$ instead of $x ∈ B$. Thank you very much!! Yes, I've already seen that there's a question about infinite DeMorgan's law question. But what I'm confused of here if about the second identity of Infinite Demorgan's law. And I'm hoping someone would help me understand, if I let $x$ be arbitrary and later want to prove that $x \in B$.

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to
[make it take up less vertical space](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189) --
this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions.
See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future
questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you very much, @GNUSupporter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Infinite DeMorgan laws](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207570/infinite-demorgan-laws)

Comment: Yes, I'm hoping to see the proof of the second identity. Thanks :-) @AlexVong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
x\in B\setminus\Big(\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i\Big) &\iff x\in B \wedge \neg \Big(x \in \bigcup_{i\in I} A_i\Big)\iff x\in B \wedge \neg (\exists i\in I: x\in A_i)\\
&\iff x\in B \wedge \forall i\in I: x\notin A_i\iff \forall i\in I: x\in B \wedge x\notin A_i\\
&\iff \forall i \in I: x\in B\setminus A_i\iff x\in \bigcap_{i\in I} \,(B\setminus A_i)\end{align}

Comment: I dont understand why it is justified to do so in line 2. Why is  ∀i∈I:x∈B∧x∉Ai equal to x∈B∧∀i∈I:x∉Ai. how to drag the  x∈B out from inside the universal quantifier. Isn't it equal to (∀i∈I:x∈B)∧(∀i∈I:x∉Ai) instead of x∈B∧∀i∈I:x∉Ai? Thanks

Comment: How to justify that x∈B⟺∀i∈I:x∈B

Comment: The reason is that $x\in B$ does not depend on the variable quantified in $\forall i\in I$, namely $i$. So it does not matter if it's in front or not. Also the universal quantifier distributes over conjunction, i.e. $\forall x(A\wedge B)\leftrightarrow \forall x A \wedge \forall x B$.

Comment: ∀i∈I:x∈B is equivalent to x∈B because x∈B does not depend on the variable quantified in ∀i∈I. But then let i be arbitrary. if I let P be i∈I and Q be x∈B. how can I conclude Q by knowing only P->Q?

Comment: so if I have any statement ∀i∈I:x∈B, I can always conclude x∈B, and the other around too? ∀i∈R:x∈B and ∀i∈I:x∈B is equal also?

Comment: First notice that $\forall i\in I: x\in B$ is short for $\forall i: i\in I \rightarrow x\in B$. Now in our case, if we take $x\in B$ as premisse, then $i\in I\rightarrow x\in B$ is true for arbitrary $i$, since an implikation is always true if the consequence is true. And since $i$ was arbitrary you can quantify over it.

Comment: But how can we know that the consequence is true, it is true that i∈I -> x∈B  is true for arbitrary i, but we don't know if i∈I is true/wrong and x∈B is true/wrong, so how can we conclude x∈B? Thanks

Comment: What if I let I be the set of all boys and B the set of all old man. Then  ∀i:i∈I→x∈B means that "For all i if i is a boy then x is an old man." But how can we conclude that x is an old man if we don't know if i is a boy. Please help, thanks.

Comment: We can assume that $x\in B$ is true, since it appears in a conjunction. We do not conclude $x \in B$, it is assumed from the very beginning, since it appears in a conjunction in the first line.

Comment: Which conjuction? ∀i:i∈I→x∈B <-> x∈B

Comment: No, in the $\Rightarrow$ direction, in $x\in B\wedge \not (x\in \cup_{i\in I}A_i$).

Comment: Thanks, but what about in the direction <-- . We can't assume x∈B is true.

Comment: I think the only part that needs an explanation in the other direction is $x\in B \wedge \forall i\in I: x\notin A_i\Leftarrow \forall i\in I: x\in B \wedge x\notin A_i$. This is true because we can distribute the universal quantifier over conjunction and eliminate it for the $x\in B$ part.

Comment: Oh yes, I've understood the --> part since you've explained it with the conjuction and consequence thing, thank you, but the other part that confuses me is that we can eliminate ∀i∈I for the x∈B part. Why are we justified to do so? Thnks

Comment: How can we prove that, x∈B  ⇐ ∀i∈I:x∈B

Comment: Oh I've kind of figured it out, but need to ask you whether it is true or not, please , since you tell me that x∈B is true, so ∀i:i∈I→x∈B is true, becauce true/false -> true, is true. Now ∀i:i∈I→x∈B = ∀i:i∉I OR x∈B = ∀i:NOT(i∈I AND x∉B) = NOT ∃i∈I (i∈I AND x∉B) which we assumed to be true, so ∃i∈I (i∈I AND x∉B) must be false. The statement say that there exist some i such that i∈I and x∉B but i∈I is not an empty set, so it must be true, so x∉B must be false, thus x∈B is true. Is the argument valid? Can I assume I is not an empty set?  Thanks.

Comment: Yeah that's fine. And $\forall x: A$ always implies $A$, that's just universal quantifier elimination. You don't  have to assume it's not empty, for that it's just trivial.

Comment: Thanks!! Ohhh, I see, I've tried to see whether x∈ ⋂i∈I(B∖Ai) is true or false, and found out that it is a vacuously true statement, therefore the statement is true for any x, then B = U where U is the universe of discourse, this is false unless we let B=U thus the equality doesn't hold. And therefore I think it is same to assume I is never an empty set. I'm very grateful, thanks MightyGuy!!! @MightyGuy