# Prove $P(\cap_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty} P(A_n)$?

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

In class we proved that:

If $A_1$ is in $A_2$ and $A_2$ is in $A_3$ and ..., then

$P(\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty} P(A_n)$

By declaring the following groups: $B_n=A_n\smallsetminus A_{n-1}$

---

Now I want to prove that if $A_1$ contains $A_2$ and $A_2$ contains $A_3$ and so on, then:

$P(\cap_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty} P(A_n)$

What groups should I declare? Using the same $B_n$ doesn't help.

Comment: Apply the previous result to the sets $A_1^{c},A_2^{c},...$

Answer (score 1):

Define the sets $B_n = A_n^c$, where $A^c$ denotes the complementary of $A$. Since $A_1 \supset A_2 \supset \dots$, we have that $A_1^c \subset A_2^c \subset \dots$ and so $B_1 \subset B_2 \subset \dots$.

Notice as well that $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty B_i = (\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty A_i)^c$. Now apply your first result to these new sets to get:

$$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} P(B_n) = P(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B_n) = P((\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty A_i)^c) = 1 - P(\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty A_i)$$

But we also have that:

$$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} P(B_n) = \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} (1 - P(A_n)) = 1 -  \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} P(A_n)$$

And so $1 -  \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} P(A_n) = 1 - P(\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty A_i)$, and hence $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} P(A_n) = P(\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty A_i)$.

Answer (score 0):

$...A_3\subseteq A_2\subseteq A_1\implies  P(\cap_{n=1}^\infty A_n)=1-P(\cup_{n=1}^\infty A_n^C)$ where $A_1^C\subseteq A_2^C\subseteq A_3^C...$

$=1-\lim_{n\to\infty} P(A_n^C)=\lim_{n\to\infty}(1-P(A_n^C))=\lim_{n\to\infty} P(A_n)$

Comment: I didn't understand the first equality

Comment: $P(B)=1-P(B^C)$. Keep $B=\cap_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ and use De Morgan's law to find its complement.

Answer (score 0):

$
\newcommand{\P}{\mathrm{P}}
\newcommand{\bb}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}
$
$$
\P\bb{\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty A_n} = 1 - \P\bb{\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_n^c} = 1 - \lim_{n \to \infty} \P(A_n^c) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \bb{1 - P(A_n^c)} = \lim_{n \to \infty} P(A_n)
$$

Comment: I didn't understand the first equality

Comment: I know that P(A)=1-P(A^c)

Comment: By De Morgan's Law, we have:
$$
\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty A_n\right)^c = \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_n^c
$$
You can see more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws#Infinite_unions_and_intersections).

Comment: You can refer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207570/infinite-demorgan-laws) for the proof of the infinite version.

Comment: Last thing, before using De Morgan's Law the c should be on ⋃=1∞ why you are allowed to get it inside on each An?

Comment: I'm not applying the De Morgan's Law to $\mathrm{P}$. I'm applying it to the set $\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty A_n$, and use the fact that $\mathrm{P}(B) = 1 - \mathrm{P}(B^c)$ (so here $B = \bigcap_{i=1}^\infty A_n$).

Comment: ok but $B^c$=union of $A_n$ so you should have the complement of the union not the complement of each single $A_n$

Comment: So $B^c = \left(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_n\right)^c$, and De Morgan's Law allows us to push the $^c$ into each $A_n$, and in exchange convert $\bigcup$ to $\bigcap$.