# Gaughan's De Morgan's Law Proof Involving Indexed Sets

Tags: logic

I'm reading through Gaughan's "Introduction to Analysis" and spotted some logic that made me uneasy in Gaughan's proof of De Morgan's Laws involving indexed sets. Below are the relevant [definitions involving indexed sets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chsHU.png) that he provides and [part of the Gaughan's proof of De Morgan's Laws](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6t0t.png). I have underlined, in red, the part that made me uneasy. The reason it makes me uneasy is because the definition of unions of indexed sets states **for some $\lambda$** while in Gaughan's proof, he states **for all $\lambda$**.

I've found [this thread on proving De Morgan's Laws](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207570/infinite-demorgan-laws) and this looks like how **for some $\lambda$** should have been navigated. Am I confused and Gaughan's proof is correct or is this an actual logical error in his proof? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x \not \in \bigcup_{\lambda \in \Lambda} A_\lambda$, then $x$ cannot be in ***any*** of the $A_\lambda$'s; otherwise, it lies in the union.

Consider the simpler example of
$$
\Lambda = \{1,2\}
\qquad
A_1 = \{4,5,6\}
\qquad
A_2 = \{7,8,9\}
$$
and hence
$$
\bigcup_{\lambda \in \Lambda} A_\lambda = \{4,5,6,7,8,9\}
$$
Notice that $10 \not \in \bigcup_{\lambda \in \Lambda} A_\lambda $, and $10 \not \in A_1$ and $10 \not \in A_2$. However, $4 \in A_1$ (despite not being in $A_2$) and hence $4 \in \bigcup_{\lambda \in \Lambda} A_\lambda $.

More broadly: if
$
x \in \{z \mid P(z) \text{ is true} \}
$
then
$
x \not\in \{z \mid P(z) \text{ is false}\}
$. Consequently, note that the negation of
$$
\exists \lambda \in \Lambda \text{ such that } x \in A_\lambda
$$
is
$$\forall \lambda \in \Lambda, \text{ we have } x \not \in A_\lambda
$$
where $P$ is some logical statement (since, when taking the negation, existential quantifiers swap, and we negate the other statements).

*(If you are confused by the symbols, $\exists$ is a quantifier meaning "there exists some", and $\forall$ is a quantifier meaning "for all".)*

Hence, in conclusion:
$$
x \in \bigcup_{\lambda \in \Lambda} A_\lambda 
\iff
\exists\lambda \in \Lambda \text{ such that } x \in A_\lambda
$$
and
$$
x \not \in \bigcup_{\lambda \in \Lambda} A_\lambda 
\iff
\forall \lambda \in \Lambda, \text{ we have } x \not \in A_\lambda
$$