# Set Theoretic Notation Pertaining to the Power Set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In his book, Naive Set Theory, Halmos defines what means to be a power set  $\mathcal{P}(E)$ of some set $E$: namely, that it is the set $\{x: {x} \subset E\}$. Then he goes on about some notational matter that I don't understand. He defines the set $\mathcal{C}$ to be a set containing arbitrary subsets of $E$, in other words, $\mathcal{C} \subset \mathcal{P}(E)$. And then defines a set $\mathfrak{D}$ as such: $\mathfrak{D} = \{x\in \mathcal{P}(E) : x' \not\in \mathcal{C}\}$. If I understand correctly, $\mathfrak{D}$ is simply $\mathcal{P}(E) – C$? He then says that an alternative notation for the union and intersection of $\mathfrak{D}$ is $\bigcup _{X \in \mathcal{C}} X'$ and $\bigcap _{X \in \mathcal{C}} X'$.

Finally, he says, and what I don't understand, is that De Morgan's laws can be stated in this new notation as $(\bigcup _{X \in \mathcal{C}} X)' = \bigcap _{X \in \mathcal{C}} X'$ and $(\bigcap _{X \in \mathcal{C}} X)' = \bigcup _{X \in \mathcal{C}} X'$. I don't quite understand the reason behind this, and attempting to prove these statements, I failed. Could someone please spill some light on this, perhaps elucidate it in a more humanly manner. Also, how exactly would you go about proving it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Generalized Demorgan laws are proved in many places on this site already. E.g. here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207570/infinite-demorgan-laws

Comment: I specifically don't understand the notation that Halmos uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Halmos denotes the complement of the set $X$ by $X'$. However, you will often see the notation $X^c$.)

If $\mathcal{C} = \{ A, B \}$, DeMorgan's first law is $(A \cup B)^c = A^c \cap B^c$.  If $\mathcal{C} = \{A,B,C\}$, DeMorgan's first law is $(A \cup B \cup C)^c = A^c \cap B^c \cap C^c$. For a finite number of sets (let's say the number of sets is $n$), $\mathcal{C} = \{ A_1, A_2, \dots, A_n \}$, DeMorgan's first law is $(A_1 \cup A_2 \cup \cdots \cup A_n)^c = A_1^c \cap A_2^c \cap \cdots \cap A_n^c$.

For an infinite collection $\mathcal{C}$ of sets, sometimes (but not always) we can associate a positive integer with each set in $\mathcal{C}$. $\mathcal{C} = \{ A_1, A_2, A_3, \dots \}$. DeMorgan's first law could be written $(A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3 \cup \cdots )^c = A_1^c \cap A_2^c \cap A_3^c \cap \cdots$. Instead we use the more compact notation $( \cup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i )^c = \cap_{i=1}^{ \infty } A_i^c$.  (This is beginning to look like the general case.)

Now, for any collection $\mathcal{C}$ of sets (we do not know or do not care how many sets there are in the collection), we denote the union of the collection as $\cup \mathcal{C}$ or $\cup \{ X | X \in \mathcal{C} \}$ or $\cup_{X \in C } X$. Then the complement of the union is $( \cup_{X \in C} X )^c$.

The intersection of $\{ A^c, B^c \}$ is $A^c \cap B^c$; the intersection of a finite collection $\{ A_1^c, A_2^c, \dots, A_n^c \}$ is $A_1^c \cap A_2^c \cap \cdots \cap A_n^c$; the intersection of an infinite list $\{ A_1^c, A_2^c, \dots \}$ is $\cap_{i=1}^{ \infty } A_i^c$; the intersection of any (finite or infinite) collection $\{ X^c | X \in \mathcal{C} \}$ of complements of sets is $\cap \{ X^c : X \in \mathcal{C} \}$ or $\cap_{ X \in \mathcal{C} } X^c$.

---

$( \cup_{ X \in \mathcal{C} } X )^c = \cap_{ X \in \mathcal{C} } X^c$. Proof.

Let $x \in ( \cup_{ X \in \mathcal{C} } X )^c$. Then $x \notin \cup_{ X \in \mathcal{C} } X$. For every $X \in \mathcal{C}$, $x \notin X$. For every $X \in \mathcal{C}$, $x \in X^c$. $x \in \cap_{ X \in \mathcal{C} } X^c$. Therefore, $( \cup_{ X \in \mathcal{C} } X )^c \subset \cap_{ X \in \mathcal{C} } X^c$.

Let $x \in \cap_{ X \in \mathcal{C} } X^c$. Then for every $X \in \mathcal{C}$, $x \in X^c$. For every $X \in \mathcal{C}$, $x \notin X$. $x \notin \cup_{X \in \mathcal{C} } X$. $x \in ( \cup_{X \in \mathcal{C} } X )^c$. Therefore, $\cap_{ X \in \mathcal{C} } X^c \subset ( \cup_{X \in \mathcal{C} } X )^c$.

---

$(A \cup B )^c = A^c \cap B^c$. Proof.

Let $x \in (A \cup B)^c$. $x \notin A \cup B$. $x \notin A$ and $x \notin B$. $x \in A^c$ and $x \in B^c$. $x \in A^c \cap B^c$.  Therefore, $( A \cap B )^c \subset A^c \cap B^c$.

Let $x \in A^c \cap B^c$. $x \in A^c$ and $x \in B^c$.  $x \notin A$ and $x \notin B$.  $x \notin A \cup B$.  $x \in (A \cup B)^c$.  Therefore, $A^c \cup B^c \subset (A \cup B)^c$.

Since $( A \cap B )^c \subset A^c \cap B^c$ and $A^c \cup B^c \subset (A \cup B)^c$, $( A \cap B )^c = A^c \cap B^c$.

Answer (score 0):

First, the notational issues.

Halmos uses $\epsilon'$ to mean "not an element of". Nowadays everyone uses $\not\in$. He uses $A'$ for the complement of $A$, relative to some "universal" set. That is, in a discussion we pick some set $E$, and insist that all our sets are subsets of this. Then $E-A$ is what he calls the "absolute" complement of $A$.

There is no standard notation for this complement, but $A'$, $\bar{A}$, and $A^c$ are all in use. (For the relative complement, $A\setminus B$ is gradually replacing $A-B$ in common use.)

His definition of $\mathcal{D}$ is, in modern notation, $\mathcal{D}=\{X\in\mathcal{C}:X'\in\mathcal{C}\}$. In other words, you go through all the sets that are elements of $\mathcal{C}$, and replace each with its complement. This is *not* $\mathcal{P}(E)-\mathcal{C}$, which would be all the subsets of $E$ that not elements of $\mathcal{C}$.

For example, if $E=\mathbb{N}$ (the natural numbers), and if $\mathcal{C}$ is the family of all finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$, then $\mathcal{D}$ would be the family of all cofinite sets (of natural numbers): sets that are complements of finite sets. However, $\mathcal{P}(E)-\mathcal{C}$ would be the family of all infinite sets. This includes the cofinite sets, but also sets like the set of all even numbers, neither finite nor cofinite.

The statement of DeMorgan's Laws is I think fairly intuitive:
$$\left(\bigcup_{X\in\mathcal{C}}X\right)'=\bigcap_{X\in\mathcal{C}}X'$$
and likewise for the complement of an intersection. Justification: Suppose $m$ belongs to the left-hand side. That means that $m$ is *not* an element of any of the sets in the union. In other words, for every $X\in\mathcal{C}$, $m$ is not an element of $X$. So for every $X\in\mathcal{C}$, $m$ *is* an element of $X'$. So $m$ is an element of the intersection on the right hand side. The argument in the reverse direction is similar, as are the arguments for the other DeMorgan law.

Now, what is $\mathcal{D}$ all about? Halmos is being very fussy here; he thinks the notation $\bigcap_{X\in\mathcal{C}}X'$ needs explanation. I think that "the intersection of the complements of all the sets in $\mathcal{C}$" would have done just fine, but Halmos is more heavy-handed. He defines the family $\mathcal{D}$ as the family of the complements of the elements of $\mathcal{C}$, so that
$$\bigcap_{X\in\mathcal{C}}X'=\bigcap_{Y\in\mathcal{D}}Y$$
because $Y=X'$ is an element of $\mathcal{D}$ if and only if $X$ is an element of $\mathcal{C}$.

Just to drive the nail in the coffin, Halmos spells out the definition of $X'\in\mathcal{C}$. He says, basically, that this means $X'=Y$ with $Y\in\mathcal{C}$. (Notice that $X$ and $Y$ have switched abodes: $Y$ is now in $\mathcal{C}$, so its complement $X$ is in $\mathcal{D}$.) Then he writes out the definition of $Y=X'$ in full, even noting that it's the relative complement $E\setminus X$.

Finally, a personal opinion. While Halmos's *Naive Set Theory* is not a *bad* book on the topic, I much prefer Kaplansky's *Set Theory and Metric Spaces*. It's first three chapters cover pretty much the same material as Halmos.

Comment: I prefer Introduction to Set Theory (Third Edition) by Karel Hrbacek and Thomas Jech to Naive Set Theory by Halmos.